# How do I hide a console application user interface when using Process.Start?

Tags: c#, .net

I want to run a console application that will output a file.

I user the following code:

```
Process barProcess = Process.Start("bar.exe", @"C:\foo.txt");
```

When this runs the console window appears.  I want to hide the console window so it is not seen by the user.

Is this possible?  Is using Process.Start the best way to start another console application?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
        Process p = new Process();
        StreamReader sr;
        StreamReader se;
        StreamWriter sw;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"bar.exe");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
```

This will start a child process without displaying the console window, and will allow the capturing of the StandardOutput, etc.

Comment: i just had to do the very same thing not 2 hours ago :)

Comment: You forgot to do anything with the StreamReaders and StreamWriter.

Comment: @dangph, those aren't nexessary for the process to execute, only if you need to interact with the process, or capture its console output.  Since those requirements weren't specified in the question, i omitted them here.

Answer (score 5):

Check into ProcessStartInfo and set the WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden and the CreateNoWindow = true.

Comment: For console apps, I've found that you just need the **WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden**. You don't need the **CreateNoWindow = true**.

Answer (score 1):

If you would like to retrieve the output of the process while it is executing, you can do the following (example uses the 'ping' command):

```
var info = new ProcessStartInfo("ping", "stackoverflow.com") {
    UseShellExecute = false, 
    RedirectStandardOutput = true, 
    CreateNoWindow = true 
};
var cmd = new Process() { StartInfo = info };
cmd.Start();
var so = cmd.StandardOutput;
while(!so.EndOfStream) {
    var c = ((char)so.Read()); // or so.ReadLine(), etc
    Console.Write(c); // or whatever you want
}
...
cmd.Dispose(); // Don't forget, or else wrap in a using statement
```

Answer (score -1):

We have done this in the past by executing our processes using the Command Line programatically.