# Process.Start - ( BEGINNER ) HELP

Tags: c#, process, command

I have a .exe file written in C++. i have used;

```
Process.Start("E:\\cmdf.exe");
```

to execute the code from C#.

Now i need to:

1. hide the command prompt
2. Then to find a way to stop the command prompt (as in closing the application)

How do i do this?

Answer (score 3):

To start without command window try this:

```
var exePath = @"E:\cmdf.exe";
var p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = exePath;
p.Start();
```

Then to end the process:

```
p.Kill();
```

Answer (score 1):

See my answer here: [How do I hide a console application user interface when using Process.Start?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/436956/how-do-i-hide-a-console-application-user-interface-when-using-process-start/436967#436967)

Answer (score 1):

To add to the other answers:

There is also the [`WindowStyle` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.windowstyle.aspx) which you can set to [`WindowStyle.Hidden`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processwindowstyle.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

This is the code to Hide the command prompt it works for me hope it will help you too.

```
  Process p = new Process();
        StreamReader sr;
        StreamReader se;
        StreamWriter sw;

        ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo(@"bar.exe");
        psi.UseShellExecute = false;
        psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardError = true;
        psi.RedirectStandardInput = true;
        psi.CreateNoWindow = true;
        p.StartInfo = psi;
        p.Start();
```